# Which bonfire I must use Bonfire Ascetic to make the Doors of Pharros red phantom invader respawn?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Which bonfire I must use Bonfire Ascetic to make the Doors of Pharros red phantom invader respawn?
There is a Bonfire right before him, and other just at the end of that section, before the Rat Authority boss. Which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To respawn Bowman Guthry you must use an Ascetic on the Royal Rat Authority bonfire (Ordeals End). It is good to note that this is a good place to farm Awestones for the Company of Champions covenant as he drops one upon every death.

Some people have reported problems with Guthry invading in this area, most have seemed to have been solved by going offline. This might be due to conflicts with Rat Covenant invasions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm farming awestones. Like Rhoy the Explorer, in the Grave of Saints, seems he just appears when playing offline.

Comment: There is an invader in the grave of saints that will respawn without an ascetic.

Comment: He respawns only when Bonfire Intensity is 2 or above.

Comment: @Mondrianaire Actually, he'll respawn 12 times and then you'll have to use an ascetic before he'll respawn again.